# Django RestAPI- updating images through PUT method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble updating images using Django Rest API. I have browsed through some of the similar questions in stack overflow, but did not help.

The error I get is the following:

```
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument &#39;files&#39;
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def screenshot(request,uid):
    try:
        details=portal.objects.get(uid=uid)
    except portal.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method=='PUT':
        serializer=portalimage(details, data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer.py

```
class portalimage(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image=serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model=portal
        fields=('image',)
```

models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
```

I use curl to upload image

```
curl -k -X PUT https://localhost/screenshot/5caed0 -d "image=/path/image1.jpg"
```

Traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/var/www/display/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response

132. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/display/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view

58. return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/display/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view

71.  return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/display/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch

456. response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/var/www/display/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch

453. response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/display/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler

50. return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/display/portal/views.py" in screenshot

57.   serializer=portalimage(details, data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)
File "/var/www/display/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in __init__

94. super(BaseSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /screenshot/5caed0
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument &#39;files&#39;
```

Comment: What's the row that fails? Don't u have any invisible character around of file?  `files=request.FILES)`

Comment: from the error message, i'd imagine the portalimage() line might be the problem. Is "portalimage" a class? If so, it appears you're not using the constructor properly, by adding a kwarg it doesn't know

Comment: yes, it is the class in serializer and it fails in that line. But when I gave normal data fields it worked, I don't know why it doesn't work for files.

Comment: Mb because there's no `files` argument in [constructor](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#l85)?

Comment: Yeah, well, the base serializer class catches **kwargs, so that shouldn't be the issue, exactly. Can you show is the actual subclass code for "portalimage"?

Comment: I have already added that part of code in serializer.py.

Comment: Strange, skimming the rest_framework code, it looks like you shouldn't be getting that error. I recommend pulling up a debugger and checking the exact spot where the error occurs. It may also be that the version of rest framework you're using is different from the code i've been looking at

Comment: I have added the traceback. Could you please look at it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DRF v3, you should be able to use

```
serializer = portalimage(details, data=request.data)
```

As mentioned in the comments, files isn't a valid kwarg, but looking into the DRF ViewSet code, there is no mention of files but (from experience) it "just works".

Also, you will want to make sure you're setting the Content-Type header to "multipart/form-data"

Comment: Yes I tried that as well. It says {"image":["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]}. When I set the content type to multipart/form-data, it says {"detail":"Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"}

Comment: What about if you replace -d "image=/path/image1.jpg"  with -F "image=@/path/image1.jpg"?

Comment: The same error: "Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument &#39;files&#39;"

Comment: I removed request.files from the view. Now I get the following: curl -k -X PUT https://localhost/screenshot/1c:65:9d:c6:1c:77 -F "image=/path/image1.jpg" results to {"image":["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]} and curl -k -X PUT https://localhost/screenshot/1c:65:9d:c6:1c:77 -F "image=@/path/image1.jpg" results to {"image":["No file was submitted."]}

Comment: hmm. TBH I tend to do all of my testing with unittests rather than cURL. If you take a look: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#creating-test-requests, and in particular the "PUT and PATCH with form data" section and amend the data payload to {'image': open('/path/image1.jpg') } are you still getting the same errors?

Comment: Could you check if this is correct?                                                       >>> from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
>>> factory = APIRequestFactory()
>>> request=factory.put('/screenshot/1c:65:9d:c6:1c:77',{'image': open('/path/image1.jpg')}
... 
... 
... It doesn't show anything.

Comment: You'll want to include boundary string & encoding bits as well if that doesn't work straight out. Failing this, I think it might be down to using PUT over POST

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't show any error now, but the image is not getting updated though.                                                     request=factory.put('localhost/screenshot/1c:65:9d:c6:1c:77',content,content_type=content_type)